# EntityMetadataNotFound: No metadata for "Product" was found using typeorm

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I have express application using typeorm. I configured my `entities` like this

```
export const dataSourceInstance = () =>  {
 return new DataSource({
    type: 'postgres',
    host: process.env.PG_HOST,
    port: Number(process.env.PG_PORT),
    username: process.env.PG_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.PG_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.PG_DATABASE,
    entities: [Product, Orders, Customers],
    synchronize: true
 })
}
```

my entites are like this

```
@Entity('customers')
export class Customers extends BaseEntity {

@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
id: number;

@Column({
    nullable: true,
    length: 100
})
fullName: string;

@Column()
age: number;

@Column()
country: number;

@Column({
    nullable: false
})
city: number;

@Column({
    nullable: false
})
contactNumber: string;

@OneToMany(() => Orders, (order) => order.customers)
orders: Orders[]

@CreateDateColumn()
created_at: Date

@UpdateDateColumn()
updated_at: Date
}


@Entity('orders')
export class Orders extends BaseEntity {

@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
id: number;

@OneToOne(() => Product)
@JoinColumn()
product: Product

@Column({
    length: 500
})
description: string;

@Column({
    nullable: false
})
quantity: number;

@Column({
    nullable: false
})
amount: number;

@Column({
    nullable: false
})
paymentMethod: string;

@Column()
weight: string;

@Column()
customizeName: string;

@ManyToOne(() => Customers, (customer) => customer.orders)
customers: Customers

@ManyToMany(() => Product)
@JoinTable()
products: Product[]

@CreateDateColumn()
created_at: Date
}

@Entity('product')
export class Product extends BaseEntity {

@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
id: number;

@Column({
    unique: true,
    length: 200,
    nullable: false
})
name: string;

@Column()
description: string;

@Column({
    nullable: false
})
cost: number;

@Column({
    nullable: false
})
price: number;

@Column()
weight: string;

@CreateDateColumn()
created_at: Date
}
```

And i have my entry file is `app.ts` which is like this

```
const app = express()

app.use(morgan('dev'))
app.use('/api/v1', routes)

app.listen(PORT, async() => {
 try {
    console.log(`Server is running on PORT: ${PORT}`)
    await dataSourceInstance().initialize()
    console.info('connected to the dataabse')
 } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error in starting the server: ", err)
 }
})
```

I am intializing my datasource at the start of the server.

As you can see that i have provided `entities: [Product, Orders, Customers]` but still i am getting this error on saving the entity record

```
No metadata for \"Product\" was found.
```

Full error stack trace is here

```
EntityMetadataNotFoundError: No metadata for "Product" was found.
at DataSource.getMetadata (/Users/fahadsubzwari924/Documents/sideProjects/cwc/server/node_modules/src/data-source/DataSource.ts:427:30)
at Repository.get metadata [as metadata] (/Users/fahadsubzwari924/Documents/sideProjects/cwc/server/node_modules/src/repository/Repository.ts:52:40)
at Repository.save (/Users/fahadsubzwari924/Documents/sideProjects/cwc/server/node_modules/src/repository/Repository.ts:205:18)
at ProductService.<anonymous> (/Users/fahadsubzwari924/Documents/sideProjects/cwc/server/src/services/product.ts:8:52)
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at /Users/fahadsubzwari924/Documents/sideProjects/cwc/server/src/services/product.ts:8:71
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at __awaiter (/Users/fahadsubzwari924/Documents/sideProjects/cwc/server/src/services/product.ts:4:12)
at ProductService.createProduct (/Users/fahadsubzwari924/Documents/sideProjects/cwc/server/src/services/product.ts:7:55)
at ProductController.<anonymous> (/Users/fahadsubzwari924/Documents/sideProjects/cwc/server/src/controllers/product.controller.ts:11:50)
POST /api/v1/products 500 15.061 ms - 97
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: Does it happen upon starting the application? Can you show us the full error stack?

Comment: No, this error is happening only when i try to save a `product`. Let me add full error stack trace

Comment: Ok, I think I got the reason. Have you initialized the `dataSource` before saving `product`?

Comment: Please check the error stack trace @MostafaFakhraei

Comment: @MostafaFakhraei i think this is not the reason. I have updated my question and included my main `app.ts` file. You can see in that file that i am intializing my `dataSource` while starting the server.

Comment: Ok, then try to remove *dist*, and put a log `dataSource.isInitialized` in `product` service. to see if it is initialized properly or not.

Comment: Don't you think that `datasouce` will raise an error if it wasn't initialized properly?